# ffmpeg input seeking to zero gives a different result than not input seeking

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm using ffmpeg with input seeking to get fast results.
When seeking using the below 2 commands I get different results although I would expect the same output file

1. `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y       -i input.ts -c copy output.ts`
2. `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -ss 0 -i input.ts -c copy output.ts`

Attached are the logs and the result for reading all frames using ffprobe

```
ffprobe -i input.ts -show_frames > frames.txt
```

Below are the logs ordered by command order

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J-CFdcn_D4-UHZ1Gg8h6hjYP5Q2Py1gJ/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLfau4pEhhhCtcGICJzatdpTOaUJfqKg/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/13heMh0pzVcq4wy32RbtbUaoLLZZOiniZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are the different results? Which did you expect, which did you not expect? For example, are there missing frames at the beginning of one vs. the other?

Comment: @Attie The expected is #1
There is about 2 seconds of video skipped in #2